# Conditional rendering with *ngTemplateOutlet not works inside formGroup correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, ng-template

I built a reusable form input that should be rendered inside the form either with a parent `formGroupName` or as normal input control.

My code look like this:

**child.component.html**:

```html
 <ng-container *ngIf="hasFormGroup; then formFieldWithGroupName else formField">
 </ng-container>

<ng-template #formFieldWithGroupName>
   <span>control With Group Name</span>
   <div formGroupName="_general">
     <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="formField"></ng-container>

     <!-- MY ISSUE HERE: directly add the template below works but not best practice -->
     <!-- <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                          [formControlName]="controlName">  -->
   </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #formField>
   <span>control Without Group Name</span><br>
   <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                   [formControlName]="controlName"> 
</ng-template>
```

**child.component.ts**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective, Validators, FormBuilder, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  childForm;
  @Input() hasFormGroup: boolean = false;
  @Input() controlName: string;
  constructor(private parentF: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.childForm = this.parentF.form;

    if(this.hasFormGroup) {
      this.childForm.controls._general.addControl(this.controlName, new FormControl());
    } else {
      this.childForm.addControl(this.controlName, new FormControl())
    }
  }

}
```

And the content of the parent component **app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <app-child [controlName]="'projectName'" [hasFormGroup]="false"></app-child>
  <app-child [controlName]="'projectName'" [hasFormGroup]="true"></app-child>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <app-child-2></app-child-2>

  Form Value: {{parentForm.value | json}}
</form>
```

The control inside the group not work as expected. But if I use the template directly (without rendering with ngTemplateOutlet) it's take both value correctly.

Can someone please help me to find out why it's not working?

Debugging the rendered element show that all directives was rendered.

Here the Stackblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-magic-4k6m9h

Answer (score 0):

The `input` control cannot get its parent because it is injected without context. Put the reference **inside** the template so that the directive can see it when it looks for it:

```html
<ng-template #formField>
  <div formGroupName="_general">
    <span>control Without Group Name</span><br>
    <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                    [formControlName]="controlName"> 
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Ho right, edit**:

Replace all your code with just the `input` and use `null` to cancel the `formGroupName` when not relevant (remove all templates & stuff):

```html
<div [formGroupName]="hasFormGroup ? '_general' : null">
  <input matInput placeholder="Project name" 
                  [formControlName]="controlName">
</div>
```

Comment: But the second instance of the component does need a parent formGroupName.. How would you deal with this ?

Comment: edited the answer. You don't need templates & stuff, or I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: Already tried this way.. Then only the input inside the group works and the other not responding to value changes

Comment: see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-magic-kygp7z